# ¿Porque me retorna error una propiedad no mapeada que retorna otra propiedad?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Buenas quería consultar, tengo un error de navegación en una clase de EF donde no es soportada la navegación por Linq, quisiera saber si alguien le paso esto y si tienen alguna sugerencia de como podría solucionar mi problema.

Error:
The specified type member 'Prop2' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported

Clases

```
// Clase que contiene la propiedad a consumir
public Class1
{
  public Class1
  {
     Prop1 = new HashSet<Class2>();
  }
  public virtual HashSet<Class2> Prop1 {get;set;}

  // Propiedad no mapeada
  public HashSet<Class2> Prop2 => Prop1.Where(x => x.IsActive).ToHashSet();
}

// Para consumir intento hacer esto y me retorna el error  
var miObjeto = DbContenxt.Class1.Where(x => x.Prop2.Any());
```

Desde ya agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar